# How can I upgrade Windows Installer from inside an MSI (using WiX)? Is it possible?

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

I've currently got an .exe that bootstraps a bunch of prerequisites (NET3.5, hotfixes, ...), including upgrades to Windows Installer (I need 3.1), and then finally runs my msi.

I'd like switch this to have an .msi that does everything, and calls an embedded binary for each prereq.  Hopefully this'll be less error-prone plus I can integrate the UI better.

Before I go sinking time into this, does anyone know if it's possible and/or a good idea?  I'm thinking start the msi, and if the installer version is too low then upgrade it and use a customaction return="asyncNoWait" to run the newly installed version on the same msi.

I'm new to  installers, so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: WiX 3.5 has a bootstrapper project called Burn that they are working on. Its in very early stages but you might give it a look. At some point it might fit your needs.

Comment: Yeah, I'm definitely interested in that, I just need something sooner.  Also sad. :(  Thanks a lot for noting it, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294961/chained-msis-bootstrapper-prerequisite) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567592/bootstrapper-how-to-compile-the-application-and-prerequisite-in-single-msi-pack) depressing SO [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427775/wix-and-net-framework-pre-requisites).

Can't be done. So sad.

UPDATE: WIX 3.6 (currently beta) has Burn! WIN! http://wix.sourceforge.net/downloadv36.html

Comment: In fact the last post you link to "questions" contains a link to more information on a new WIX bootstrapper feature called Burn. In essence WIX will have its own bootstrapper tool in the near future. Let me add a direct link: http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2009/7/14/Lets-talk-about-Burn

Answer (score 1):

Try [dotNetInstaller](http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com/) to do the dependency checking and install the Windows Installer update before launching your MSI.