# Bootstrapper: Check if msi version is installed before running

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper, merge-module

I'm trying to find a solution for the following issue:

I have numerous programs (lets call them slaves) that all rely on a single program (master).  I need to distribute an installer for each slave.  This installer needs to install the master.

I want to be able to version both pieces, so multiple msi's appear to be the right solution, chained with a bootstrapper.

My problem is if a slave installer installs the same version of the master that is already installed, the .msi will run in repair/remove mode.

This is unacceptable from a user standpoint and will just cause confusion.

Is there any way to check for a version of the currently installed fiels before trying to run the msi?

I am currently using WIX's setupbld.exe as a bootstrapper.

Any other solutions greatly appreciated (I have also tried merge modules with no success, since the versioning is useless)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `setupbld.exe` (which I don't really know as I can't find any documentation) you can use msbuild's [generatebootstrapper task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164294.aspx). The wix documentation already covers how to use this task to generate a bootstrapper that installs the .NET framework. See [How To: Install the .NET Framework Using a Bootstrapper](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/install_dotnet.htm). This makes use of the pre-defined bootstrapper packages.

However, in this case you will also have to **author your own bootstrapper packages**. One way to do this is to study the existing bootstrapper packages in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\BootStrapper\Packages\` (or the ones in the [Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c17ba869-9671-4330-a63e-1fd44e0e2505&displaylang=en)) and read the [documentation of the Bootstrapper Manifest XML format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229223.aspx). The [bootstrapper generator](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/bmg) tool might also be helpful.

To determine whether the package needs to be installed, you can use one of the [InstallChecks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229432.aspx) to set a property, and then check the property value in a `InstallCondition` under the [Commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229510.aspx) element.

If you're thinking that this is all harder than it should be — I agree, but it's what I've used so far. There are some alternatives which I have not tried yet:

- the poorly named [dotNetInstaller](http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com/)
  which is actually a general purpose
  bootstrapper generator.
- the [wix 3.5 burn](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2009/7/14/Lets-talk-about-Burn) bootstrapper which is not yet released. I'm not sure if it is in a usable state yet.

Comment: I ended up using dotNetInstaller, and have found that while not perfect, it is better than using the Microsoft boostrappers (couldn't get them to work how I needed).

So far every thing I've tried to do with dotNetInstaller has worked.  Although sometimes it needs a little guidance.